# Grunt - Replace blank lines in a file - regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, gruntjs

I'm building up my first Grunt project and one of my tasks is introducing blank lines into the beginning of my output html files.  I'd like to remove them.

I found [grunt-line-remover](https://github.com/davidtucker/grunt-line-remover) but it requires me to list each html file separately, and I'd rather point it to a directory.  (and I don't have time right now to figure out how to tweak the code to do that.)

I then found [grunt-text-replace](https://github.com/yoniholmes/grunt-text-replace) which supports file name pattern matching, but I can't figure out the Regex for finding a blank line in an html file.

I tried

```
/\n/g
```

but that replaces every new line whereas I'd like to just replace the empty lines.  Really, I just want to replace the beginning blank lines, but if it removes every blank line that's fine.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove empty space Try using a regex of  [\r\n]{2,}

Comment: Damn!  That's awesome!  Works perfectly!  Can you add in some explanation of how that works- i.e. how it only removes the leading blank lines, but none else?  (so psyched!)

Comment: it's basically searching for the common "line feed" and "Carriage return" combination instead of just empty space.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for newlines, you can look for empty lines with the regex

```
/^\s*$/gm
```

It should give you empty lines as well as lines containing spaces only.